# How can I segment bones from an x ray image?

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, adaptive-threshold

I want to remove the skin particles from my X-Ray of hand image. I want bones as white Color and all other areas including the skin area in the x ray as black. I am doing my project in mat lab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8647-local-adaptive-thresholding) for **Local Adaptive Thresholding**.

Or if you want bones as white color you should use **sobel-operator**, as in [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detecting-a-cell-using-image-segmentation.html).

Comment: I tried that methods but the bone seperation is difficult and the some of the bone regions are also removing by this methode..

Answer (score 0):

A simple way,you can just change the value of a pixel, when it is higher than 125 change it to 255,or set 0. the number 125,you can change it,to get a best one.
you can search "binarization" on google to get more information.

Comment: But i want to separate each bones in an x ray also. that means each bone white colour and all others background and skin and gap between each bones are also to be black.. can you help?